# Web Push Notification on static web apps

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, push-notification, github-pages

Is it Possible to implement Web Push Notifications on static FrontEnd(CRUD) Web application hosted on Github Pages?
The said web app was created using reactjs

Comment: Usually you need a backend and a database to store the push subscriptions and send the push messages. If you don't want to build the backend yourself you can use a "Backend as a Service": you can use any push service, like Pushpad, OneSignal, Firebase Cloud Messaging, etc.